# ng-repeat + Filter + ng-switch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following `ng-repeat` that gets 3 items at a time:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:search | filter:customFilter">
              <span ng-switch="" on="$index % 3">
                        <div class="row" ng-switch-when="0">
                             <div class="col-sm-4">
                                  {{posts[(posts.indexOf(post))]}}
                             </div>
                             <div class="col-sm-4">
                                  {{posts[(posts.indexOf(post + 1))]}}
                             </div>
                             <div class="col-sm-4">
                                  {{posts[(posts.indexOf(post + 2))]}}
                             </div>
                        </div>
              </span>
</div>
```

My problem is that if the `search` or `customFilter` apply to one post, I will get all three items even though the second and third ones don't apply.

[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/nUx4YWbEPv9ujCEsZj3r?p=preview)

In that PLNKR if you search for "1", you will get three items instead of just one.

Is there a way to filter one item at a time as opposed to all 3 at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the filtered values in a variable like this

```
post in filteredPosts = (posts | filter:search | filter:customFilter)
```

the use the `filteredPosts.length` plus `ng-show / ng-hide` to hide the extra items

Edit: Apparently just using a filtered variable, and using it to get the posts in the `{{}}` (like `filteredPosts[(filteredPosts.indexOf(post))]`) works just fine.

Is this what you want? [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dIo3jUXsHZvyG3l1c87r?p=preview)